# Rails, passing an array using radio button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, radio-button

I'm making a search form in rails, I have different radio fields, I have no problems with those ones, but I'm having trouble with the last one, what I want is a radio button that when active enables two text-fields, in which you write two different dates (basically a date range) and then passes on an array with the dates in the range.

The radio button is already in place and the text-fields get active only when the last one is selected, and gets disabled when selecting the others, I have that part down, also I know how to include an array with a range of dates, the problem I have is that I don't know how to take the values in my text-fields, manipulate them (that is, use them to generate the array) and then pass it on to the controller and view (which is working fine already.)

Here is a the last part of my form

```
f.radio_button :dates, "", id: "true_date" 
label :date, "Elige tu fecha" 
f.text_field :dates, class: "dates_cal", id: "from", :disabled => true
f.text_field :dates, class: "dates_cal", id: "to", :disabled => true
```

Is there a way to take the values from both text_fields and use them before passing them on? or use them inside the controller and passing on them as an array in :dates? or am I making this a lot harder to myself and there is a far simplier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retreive the values from the text fields (i.e. `from` and `to`) in your controller and create the array there; something like this:

```
date_from = params[:from].to_date
date_to   = params[:to].to_date

date_array = (date_from..date_to).to_a
```

If you will use it as a range, then there is no need to convert it to array.